# sort list of tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I have a structure looking like this

```
d= { 'image0' : [(image0, image1, 31.58), (image0, image2, 31.56), (image0, image3, 54.65)], 'image2' : [(image0, image2, 31.56), (image1, image2, 45.87), (image2, image3, 14.25)] ...}
```

and I would like it to be sorted by key and then by the last element of each tuple. 
Basically, i'd want somethink like this :

```
d= { 'image0' : [(image0, image2, 31.56), (image0, image1, 31.58), (image0, image3, 54.65)], 'image2' : [(image2, image3, 14.25), (image0, image2, 31.56),(image1, image2, 45.87)] ...}
```

I have a list `liste_im=[image0, image2]` so i wrote this :

```
a={}
for i in range(len(liste_im)):
    a=sorted(d[str(liste_im[i])], key=lambda x: x[1][2])
```

but it doesn't work : it gives me this result :

```
[(image0, image2, 31.56), (image2, image1, 45.87), (image2, image3, 14.25)]
```

, so i tried this :

```
a=d.items()
for i in range(len(liste_im)):    
    a.sort(key=lambda x:x[1][i][2])
```

and it gives me this :

```
[('image0',[(image0, image2, 31.56), (image0, image1, 31.58), (image0, image3, 54.65)]), ('image2',[(image2, image3, 14.25), (image0, image2, 31.56),(image1, image2, 45.87)])]
```

just a list from my dictionary, but not sorted wheras there is the a.sort(...)

I hope someone can help me
Thank you

Comment: You can do that by calling `.sort()` two times.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* and *"still not working"* aren't problem descriptions, please give a [mcve].

Comment: @giuscri yes i know but the dictionary d is not always the same thing, at the beginning there are only 2 'imageX' but there can be 10 or 20 different keys 'imageX'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the values first, then the keys (items):

```
from operator import itemgetter   
for v in d.values():
    v.sort(key=itemgetter(2))

a = sorted(d.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with your lambda function, looks like too much indexing than needed.

Regardless, since `d['imagex']` would return a list of your tuples, that means you can call `.sort(..)` on it with `key = lambda x: x[2]`. Like below:

```
for itemKey in d:
     d[itemKey].sort(key = lambda x: x[2])
```

Comment: thank you, it works as well :) 
Eventually i have chosen your solution